# Sqoop exporting partitioned Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I encountered some problems when trying to export a partitioned Hive table. Is this fully supported (I tried to google for it and found one JIRA ticket)?

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb --table sales --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/sales --direct
```

And here is what I get:

```
00000_2, Status : FAILED
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/hive/warehouse/sales/day=2013-04-01
```

Running

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/sales/day=2013-04-01
```

shows that this directory actually exists.

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks in advance,
Diddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop currently do not support export for recursive directories. There is a JIRA [SQOOP-951](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-951) for adding such support. The workaround for the time being is to export one partition at the time or temporarily copy your data to non partitioned table.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, but in case somebody stumbles upon it, please use

```
--export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/sales/*"
```

to export all partitions within a table.