# Sqoop export HIVE partitioned column

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am exporting a Hive partitioned table to Teradata. How can the **partitioned column** be included in the export?

I know this can be done by copying the data to  HDFS directory and then using that directory as source for sqoop export. Is there an one step approach to include the partitioned column during export?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sqoop exporting partitioned Hive table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133595/sqoop-exporting-partitioned-hive-table)

Comment: Did you get a solution to this problem?